# Weird continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I = [a,b]$ and let $f : I \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function on $I$ such that for each $x$ in $I$ there exists $y$ in $I$ such that $| f(y)|\le  | f(x)|/2$. Prove there exists a point $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

I don't know how to approach this question. Help!

Answer (score 2):

The map $\left\vert f\right \vert\colon I\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. As $I$ is compact, it thus attains a minimum. Now use your assumption about $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an arbitrary $x \in [a,b]$, get a $y$ by your definition. Call that $y$ $x_1$ instead. Repeat with $x_1$ by your definition, get a $y$, call it $x_2$. Iterate this procedure. Now you get a sequence $x_n$ with $|f(x_n)| \leq 2^{-n} |f(x)|$. Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: Okay, I see.

Can I also take a limit rather than iterating it over and over?

Comment: @JLIU You take a limit on both sides of the inequality to finish the proof, yes. But it's not clear (to me at least) what you would take a limit of to avoid doing this iteration procedure.

Comment: given f(y) <= 1/2 f(x), I will continuously keep finding function values at y that are smaller than half of the function values at x, and if I take the limit of this eventually there will be a function value of c that = 0?

I could be completely wrong here, but in my crazy mind this kinda makes sense

Comment: @JLIU That may not necessarily get you an actual function value of zero in the sequence. For instance with $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ you can start at $1$, then $1/2$, then $1/4$, etc.